# Unable to access a service with absolute binding address

Tags: wcf

I am having a WCF Service Library. By default i am having a base address and i commented that out and added the complete address when specifying the end point address. Now when i try to access the wcf service through endpoint address i am not able to do that.

1.I created a WCF service library project in Visual Studio

2.By Default in the web.config we are having a base address for my service and my end point is having ""(relative address)

3.As per my understanding i am assuming that base address is not compulsory when we have complete address in EndPoint..Is my understanding correct?

3a. Now i removed my base address and added the complete url in the endpoint(please see attached config on what i did)

[image]

4.Now i tried to click on f5 in the visual studio solution then the default hosting screen came with an error.

5.Also i copied the complete url that i specified in the endpoint and pasted it in the web browser but i am getting 404 error..

6.Is it compulsory to have a base address to expose the service that was created using WCF Service library template??

So please let me know where i am committing the mistake. I am attaching my configuration.

```
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services>
  <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
    <!--<host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>-->
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Service2/pavan" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
    </endpoint>
    <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Service2/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: please figure out what was the problem..

Comment: There's nowhere  near enough information in your question to even begin to figure out the issue.  How are you hosting the service?  How are you calling the service?  Can you access the service via a browser?  Are you getting an error?  Contrary to what appears to be a very popular belief on Stack Overflow, no one here has a crystal ball or can read other people's minds.....

Comment: Tim updated my question...can you check that

Comment: @PavanKumarAryasomayajulu - What does the WCF Test client tell you when you click on the service to get a more detailed error message ("To view detailed information, select a service in the list above")?.  Also, you said you created a library - are you hosting it with a .svc file that points to the DLL?  Libraries are not executable - you need to host it in a consuming service (in IIS that can be done with via the .svc file).

Comment: @Tim - This is the error i am getting
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

Thanks,

Comment: @Tim -- So My question is it compulsory to have BaseAddress when we are dealing with WCF Service library project type and hosting it on WCF Service host(The default host that was provided by Microsoft when we click f5)